# Angular 6/7 generating data summary from array any (any[])

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array which is
fruits: any[] and is displayed in front-end through a grid
that look like this

`+ID----+Name------+Value+
|0     |Apple     |    4|
|1     |Orange    |    1|
|2     |Banana    |    3|
|1     |Orange    |    3|
|0     |Apple     |    1|
+------+----------+-----+`

And I need a result like this

`+ID----+Name----+Value+
|0     |Apple   |    5|
|1     |Orange  |    4|
|2     |Banana  |    3|
+------+--------+-----+`

I mean, I can achieve this using the backend, but I am pulling a large amount of data which take some time to generate. This is a reporting project with 2 types, detailed and summarized. I'm just thinking that upon generating the detailed data, I already have the summarized data, then why not do it in the front-end, if possible. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Can you share your fruits array?

Comment: so basically you need to display the array sortde by value DESC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a service that aggregates or in general preprocesses your data and use that service in your component.

Suppose you have the following data That you receive from the server:

```
fruit = [
    {
      id:0,
      name:"Apple",
      value:4
    },
    {
      id:1,
      name:"Orange",
      value:1
    },
     {
      id:2,
      name:"Banana",
      value:3
    },
    {
      id:1,
      name:"Orange",
      value:3
    },
    {
      id:0,
      name:"Apple",
      value:1
    }
  ];
```

Create a service for example

**Preprocess.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PreprocessService {

  aggregatedFruits: any = {};
  constructor() {}


  /**
  * takes list of fruits and keep  aggregated data in aggregatedFruits variable
  */
  summarize(fruitList: any[]) :any {
    fruitList.forEach(el => {
      if(!this.aggregatedFruits[el.id]) {
        this.aggregatedFruits[el.id] = el
      } else {
        this.aggregatedFruits[el.id].value += el.value
      }
    });
    return this.aggregatedFruits
  }
}
```

Then in your component

**Your.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PreprocessService } from './Preprocess.service';
.
.
.
  constructor(public preprocessService: PreprocessService) { }

  aggFruits: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.aggFruits = this.preprocessService.summarize(fruit);
    console.log(this.aggFruits);
  }
.
.
.
```

Benefit of creating a separate service for preprocessing data is that you can extend its functionalities and it does not clutter your component with code that has nothing to do with handling the user interface.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

use this and let me know if it is working for you or not

```
 newFruit:any[]=[];

     fruit:any[]=[
       {
         id:0,
         name:"A",
         value:2
       },
       {
         id:1,
         name:"B",
         value:2
       },
        {
         id:1,
         name:"B",
         value:3
       },
       {
         id:0,
         name:"A",
         value:3
       }
     ]
      ngOnInit()
      {
        this.fruit.forEach(f=>{
            let d=this.newFruit.find(x=>{
              if(x.id==f.id)
              return true;
            })
            if(d)
            {
              d.value+=f.value;
            }
            else
            {
              this.newFruit.push(f);
            }
        })
      }
```

Comment: it's always better to __explain__ what you did beside posting code